# SceneKit – Get Node's height

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nodes, scenekit

I have a SceneKit project in which I currently have 2 objects, a ground which is a simple plane and a pyramid. I want to set the height of the pyramid node to something like the following sudo code:

```
pyr.position = SCNVector3Make(0, ground.position.y+pyr.size.height, 0)
```

Is there a way to get the height of nodes in pixels or points?

**NOTE**

This is how I created the `pyr` & `ground` nodes:

```
let pyr = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("pyramid", recursively: true)!
let ground = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("ground", recursively: true)!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Have you tried this?*

From the docs:

The **SCNBoundingVolume protocol** defines an interface for describing objects that occupy a volume in space, adopted by the SCNNode and SCNGeometry classes. Its methods measure the location and size of an object in the object’s local coordinate space, expressed as either a box or a sphere.

Gets the minimum and maximum corner points of the object’s bounding box.

```
    func getBoundingBoxMin(_ min: UnsafeMutablePointer<SCNVector3>,
               max max: UnsafeMutablePointer<SCNVector3>) -> Bool
```

> min
> On output, the minimum coordinates of the bounding box.
>
> max
> On output, the maximum coordinates of the bounding box.

**(max.y - min.y) would be the height.**

Comment: Totally forgot I once asked that question, thanks for the answer. Can you explain why that method returns a *bool*?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth The documentation states: "Return Value: YES if the object has a nonzero volume; otherwise, NO."